# typescript and reactjs : how to use map - ERROR ts(7053)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

this is my first asked question in here, so please help me to improve.

In Typescript (ReactJs) given two arrays:

```
const array1:String = ["prop1", "prop2"];
const array2:MyType = { prop1 : "value1", prop2: "value2 }
```

where MyType is a kind:

```
type MyType = {
  prop1: string, 
  prop2: string
}
```

how can i print "value1" with the following code?

```
console.log(array1.map(x => array2[x])
```

Right now I'am getting the following error:

```
const array2: MyType
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyType'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyType'.ts(7053)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're off to a good start, but there are a few things to fix!

Firstly, your first code snippet has incorrect types:

```js
const array1:String = ["prop1", "prop2"];
const array2:MyType = { prop1 : "value1", prop2: "value2 }
```

`array1` isn't a `String`, it's an array of strings. So its type should be `string[]`. You're also missing a quote after `"value2`:

```js
const array1: string[] = ["prop1", "prop2"];
const array2: MyType = { prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2" }
```

Next, you have a syntax error in your `console.log`—it's missing the ending `)`:

```js
console.log(array1.map(x => array2[x]))
```

Then lastly @CertainPerformance's answer can come in and save you: the type of `array1` can be made more specific.

```js
const array1: (keyof MyType)[] = ["prop1", "prop2"];
// or, equivalently
const array1: Array<keyof MyType> = ["prop1", "prop2"];
```

All together now:

```js
type MyType = {
  prop1: string, 
  prop2: string
}

const array1: (keyof MyType)[] = ["prop1", "prop2"];
const array2: MyType = { prop1 : "value1", prop2: "value2" }

console.log(array1.map(x => array2[x]))
```

Now, you asked about how to print `value1`. This will actually log `["value1", "value2"]`. To log only the first one you can just access the first element after your `.map()`:

```js
console.log(array1.map(x => array2[x])[0])
```

Comment: You right. I should have wrote the code on a compiler first! Sorry for stupid mistake.However that's clear know that in order to address the right property of an object the type should be (keyof MyType). Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

`const array1:String` is not specific enough (and even if you had to do something like that, use `string`, not `String`). Specify that `array1` contains keys of the object (which should probably be called something like `myTypeObj` - it's an object, not an array):

```
type MyType = {
    prop1: string,
    prop2: string
}
const myTypeObj: MyType = { prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2" };
const array1: Array<keyof MyType> = ["prop1", "prop2"];

console.log(array1.map(x => myTypeObj[x])
```

Another option is to just keep TS from automatically widening the `array1` items to `string`:

```
const array1 = ["prop1", "prop2"] as const;
```